# Parse PHP/HTML to shapefile or similar

Tags: python, shapefile, php, html

I've been experimenting with scraping spatial data from a web page ([www.majidata.co.ke](http://www.majidata.co.ke)). I've managed to find the source of the vector data from within a webpage though and have saved a chunk as HTML for example this relates to some polygons:`39.655756,-4.034769 39.655757,-4.034769 39.655758,-4.034769 39.655800,-4.034788 39.655885,-4.034809 39.655977,-4.034861 39.656021,-4.034878 39.656033,-4.034858 39.656127,-4.034883 39.656194,-4.034850 39.656165,-4.034810 39.656144,-4.034763 39.656085,-4.034735 39.656065,-4.034732 39.656062,-4.034593 39.656045,-4.034521 39.656044,-4.034493 39.656008,-4.034416 39.655976,-4.034420 39.655952,-4.034409 39.655938,-4.034412 39.655929,-4.034398 39.655867,-4.034358 39.655809,-4.034354 39.655798,-4.034312 39.655803,-4.034246 39.655768,-4.034227 39.655681,-4.034251 39.655573,-4.034372 39.655569,-4.034373 39.655534,-4.034409 39.655499,-4.034411 39.655459,-4.034412 39.655409,-4.034399 39.655401,-4.034397 39.655331,-4.034413 39.655247,-4.034424 39.655185,-4.034420 39.655161,-4.034431 39.655092,-4.034426 39.655007,-4.034467 39.654996,-4.034477 39.654991,-4.034478 39.654947,-4.034459 39.654946,-4.034459 39.654931,-4.034462 39.654878,-4.034474 39.654876,-4.034474 39.654816,-4.034461 39.654816,-4.034459 39.654814,-4.034458 39.654738,-4.034457 39.654688,-4.034450 39.654588,-4.034443 39.654584,-4.034452 39.654551,-4.034594 39.654542,-4.034636 39.654540,-4.034636 39.654530,-4.034627 39.654479,-4.034630 39.654378,-4.034657 39.654352,-4.034658 39.654302,-4.034675 39.654302,-4.034676 39.654302,-4.034677 39.654305,-4.034681 39.654304,-4.034780 39.654307,-4.034784 39.654308,-4.034786 39.654281,-4.034901 39.654287,-4.034905 39.654343,-4.034898 39.654366,-4.034885 39.654367,-4.034848 39.654382,-4.034842 39.654379,-4.034844 39.654450,-4.034841 39.654471,-4.034848 39.654503,-4.034874 39.654560,-4.034850 39.654652,-4.034810 39.654709,-4.034767 39.654739,-4.034732 39.654789,-4.034723 39.654800,-4.034713 39.654806,-4.034710 39.654840,-4.034724 39.654907,-4.034722 39.655025,-4.034717 39.655055,-4.034623 39.655084,-4.034614 39.655093,-4.034616 39.655170,-4.034661 39.655182,-4.034663 39.655229,-4.034660 39.655263,-4.034655 39.655338,-4.034669 39.655379,-4.034663 39.655399,-4.034686 39.655510,-4.034747 39.655596,-4.034750 39.655756,-4.034769|BANDARINI|#FF0000!39.660949,-4.031741 39.660951,-4.031718 39.660953,-4.031715 39.661011,-4.031725 39.661032,-4.031725 39.661032,-4.031725 39.661033,-4.031714 39.661062,-4.031671 39.661076,-4.031659 39.661067,-4.031645 39.661035,-4.031595 39.661046,-4.031431 39.661077,-4.031377 39.661074,-4.031320 39.661060,-4.031240 39.661077,-4.031188 39.661064,-4.031057 39.661069,-4.031024 39.661037,-4.030952 39.661034,-4.030820 39.661033,-4.030818 39.660999,-4.030805 39.660981,-4.030804 39.660979,-4.030803 39.660961,-4.030786 39.660960,-4.030786 39.660917,-4.030802 39.660909,-4.030805 39.660903,-4.030805 39.660860,-4.030786 39.660819,-4.030768 39.660816,-4.030768 39.660739,-4.030793 39.660725,-4.030847 39.660735,-4.030916 39.660727,-4.030948 39.660741,-4.030969 39.660738,-4.031017 39.660724,-4.031156 39.660722,-4.031236 39.660732,-4.031300 39.660665,-4.031377 39.660584,-4.031489 39.660575,-4.031641 39.660583,-4.031675 39.660567,-4.031725 39.660587,-4.031841 39.660575,-4.031919 39.660575,-4.031921 39.660577,-4.031940 39.660560,-4.031996 39.660559,-4.032016 39.660537,-4.032058 39.660525,-4.032150 39.660503,-4.032191 39.660558,-4.032219 39.660561,-4.032248 39.660564,-4.032350 39.660568,-4.032391 39.660553,-4.032414 39.660587,-4.032424 39.660646,-4.032415 39.660690,-4.032406 39.660759,-4.032373 39.660754,-4.032280 39.660769,-4.032283 39.660780,-4.032194 39.660793,-4.032155 39.660838,-4.032112 39.660830,-4.031981 39.660827,-4.031967 39.660829,-4.031945 39.660871,-4.031795 39.660867,-4.031770 39.660869,-4.031767 39.660949,-4.031741|PARADISE A|#FF0000!39.660122,-4.032298 39.660153,-4.032287 39.660191,-4.032290 39.660305,-4.032335 39.660370,-4.032356 39.660442,-4.032406 39.660507,-4.032439 39.660529,-4.032435 39.660568,-4.032391 39.660565,-4.032389 39.660562,-4.032349 39.660565,-4.032315 39.660522,-4.032223 39.660511,-4.032217 39.660477,-4.032185 39.660511,-4.032109 39.660500,-4.032088 39.660519,-4.032066 39.660526,-4.032046 39.660552,-4.031983 39.660593,-4.031891 39.660597,-4.031883 39.660586,-4.031782 39.660570,-4.031650 39.660580,-4.031602 39.660551,-4.031509 39.660576,-4.031450 39.660647,-4.031354 39.660736,-4.031297 39.660738,-4.031288 39.660721,-4.031234 39.660719,-4.031175 39.660729,-4.031136 39.660736,-4.031056 39.660743,-4.030945 39.660725,-4.030880 39.660725,-4.030869 39.660716,-4.030805 39.660649,-4.030758 39.660649,-4.030754 39.660595,-4.030750 39.660533,-4.030760 39.660432,-4.030755 39.660328,-4.030770 39.660232,-4.030784 39.660131,-4.030813 39.660016,-4.030825 39.660017,-4.030826 39.659975,-4.030841 39.659883,-4.030839 39.659841,-4.030812 39.659744,-4.030835 39.659701,-4.030856 39.659636,-4.030970 39.659640,-4.031012 39.659597,-4.031058 39.659498,-4.031098 39.659498,-4.031096 39.659468,-4.031105 39.659417,-4.031145 39.659416,-4.031146 39.659416,-4.031146 39.659416,-4.031146 39.659416,-4.031147 39.659383,-4.031142 39.659368,-4.031141 39.659286,-4.031169 39.659197,-4.031164 39.659201,-4.031165 39.659040,-4.031211 39.659032,-4.031221 39.659024,-4.031259 39.658964,-4.031348 39.658954,-4.031433 39.658900,-4.031454 39.658887,-4.031467 39.658816,-4.031530 39.658791,-4.031575 39.658706,-4.031595 39.658675,-4.031583 39.658654,-4.031589 39.658538,-4.031658 39.658486,-4.031699 39.658470,-4.031732 39.658476,-4.031746 39.658504,-4.031809 39.658504,-4.031859 39.658543,-4.031909 39.658582,-4.031956 39.658634,-4.031991 39.658704,-4.032052 39.658707,-4.032059 39.658713,-4.032121 39.658711,-4.032166 39.658735,-4.032222 39.658745,-4.032265 39.658780,-4.032300 39.658778,-4.032305 39.658793,-4.032317 39.658817,-4.032313 39.658898,-4.032307 39.659022,-4.032300 39.659103,-4.032315 39.659228,-4.032285 39.659344,-4.032301 39.659359,-4.032301 39.659517,-4.032306 39.659645,-4.032301 39.659738,-4.032299 39.659786,-4.032314 39.659883,-4.032311 39.660023,-4.032302 39.660122,-4.032298|PARADISE B|#FF0000!`

I'd like to be able to parse this to a shapefile (to allow me to plot in QGIS). I can see that there is a string of coordinates, followed by "|*name of polygon|*" then followed by a hex colour for the polygon outline. I'm assuming it would be possible to use something like the Python library *Beautifulsoup* to parse this but my Python skills are a little sketchy.

Has anyone had any experience doing anything similar, or know of an easier way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to scrape data and (partially) convert it to spatial data using R.

I can scrape the data using this:

```
url = "http://www.majidata.go.ke/ajax-maps.php?reg=area&id=30202020116"
test <- readLines(url, warn="F")
```

Which gives me a character vector containing the coordinates, the name, and a hex colour.

I then split the vector into a dataframe with three columns using the `colsplit` function from `reshape2` and drop the colour column as I don't need it:

```
test_df <- colsplit(test, "\\|", c("polygon", "name", "colour"))
#first drop the colour column
test_df <- test_df[-3]
```

Now I put the coordinates in WKT format: and replace commas for spaces as the original poster suggests above:

```
    #first replace "," with a holding character "~"
test_df$polygon <- str_replace_all(test_df$polygon,",", "~")
        #now replace " " with ","
        test_df$polygon <- str_replace_all(test_df$polygon," ", ",")
        #and finally re-replace the "~" with a space " "; otherwise all spaces would get converted to ","
        test_df$polygon <- str_replace_all(test_df$polygon,"~", " ")
#now add parentheses
test_df$polygon <- paste0("POLYGON((", test_df$polygon, "))" )
```

Then I create a spatial object from the resulting data.frame using `readWKT`

I'm a little stuck here now though as I can't get this object out of R. I want to convert this spatial polygon to either a shapefile or better write it to a postGIS table. Not having much luck there so have ask another question here: [R PostGIS convert SpatialPolygon to PostGIS table](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114592/r-postgis-convert-spatialpolygon-to-postgis-table)

Thanks for the initial help though:)

Answer (score 5):

This only a partial answer and lacks all python but too long to fit into a comment field.

Your data is rather easy to convert into WKT:

- capture the coordinate part
- switch commas to spaces and spaces to commas
- close inside WKT polygon: POLYGON ((...))

  > POLYGON ((39.655756 -4.034769,39.655757 -4.034769,39.655758
  >   -4.034769,39.655800 -4.034788,39.655885 -4.034809,39.655977 -4.034861,39.656021 -4.034878,39.656033 -4.034858,39.656127 -4.034883,39.656194 -4.034850,39.656165 -4.034810,39.656144 -4.034763,39.656085 -4.034735,39.656065 -4.034732,39.656062 -4.034593,39.656045 -4.034521,39.656044 -4.034493,39.656008 -4.034416,39.655976 -4.034420,39.655952 -4.034409,39.655938 -4.034412,39.655929 -4.034398,39.655867 -4.034358,39.655809 -4.034354,39.655798 -4.034312,39.655803 -4.034246,39.655768 -4.034227,39.655681 -4.034251,39.655573 -4.034372,39.655569 -4.034373,39.655534 -4.034409,39.655499 -4.034411,39.655459 -4.034412,39.655409 -4.034399,39.655401 -4.034397,39.655331 -4.034413,39.655247 -4.034424,39.655185 -4.034420,39.655161 -4.034431,39.655092 -4.034426,39.655007 -4.034467,39.654996 -4.034477,39.654991 -4.034478,39.654947 -4.034459,39.654946 -4.034459,39.654931 -4.034462,39.654878 -4.034474,39.654876 -4.034474,39.654816 -4.034461,39.654816 -4.034459,39.654814 -4.034458,39.654738 -4.034457,39.654688 -4.034450,39.654588 -4.034443,39.654584 -4.034452,39.654551 -4.034594,39.654542 -4.034636,39.654540 -4.034636,39.654530 -4.034627,39.654479 -4.034630,39.654378 -4.034657,39.654352 -4.034658,39.654302 -4.034675,39.654302 -4.034676,39.654302 -4.034677,39.654305 -4.034681,39.654304 -4.034780,39.654307 -4.034784,39.654308 -4.034786,39.654281 -4.034901,39.654287 -4.034905,39.654343 -4.034898,39.654366 -4.034885,39.654367 -4.034848,39.654382 -4.034842,39.654379 -4.034844,39.654450 -4.034841,39.654471 -4.034848,39.654503 -4.034874,39.654560 -4.034850,39.654652 -4.034810,39.654709 -4.034767,39.654739 -4.034732,39.654789 -4.034723,39.654800 -4.034713,39.654806 -4.034710,39.654840 -4.034724,39.654907 -4.034722,39.655025 -4.034717,39.655055 -4.034623,39.655084 -4.034614,39.655093 -4.034616,39.655170 -4.034661,39.655182 -4.034663,39.655229 -4.034660,39.655263 -4.034655,39.655338 -4.034669,39.655379 -4.034663,39.655399 -4.034686,39.655510 -4.034747,39.655596 -4.034750,39.655756 -4.034769))

The result can be shown with QGIS by dropping the WKT into QuickWKT plugin (experimental).

[image]

Comment: hey thanks for the hint. I had played with the QuickWKT plugin and realise I need to parse the data into WKT to use it. I guess I'll have to sit down and figure it out in Python (or R for that matter). Do you know if its possible to scrape straight from the website to a CSV/Shapefile using Python?